Python snowflake connector fetch_pandas_all() fails with larger record count
I am attempting to export snowflake data to a csv but I am finding that the code below only works for a few records. I am unable to ascertain what the maximum number of records that it works for is because it seems to change as I re-run the script. What I know is that I can successfully run the script and get an output csv file if I set the limit in the sql query to 100. When I set the limit in the query to more than 2000 or so, the code fails to run the df = cur.fetch_pandas_all() line. Sometimes I get the error screen below but most times the code just exits. What could be the cause of the issue?
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector
import time
import csv

# Calculate the start time
start = time.time()

credentials = {
    'account'    : 'my account',
    'user'     : 'my user',
    'authenticator' : 'externalbrowser',
    'database' : ' my database',
    'schema' : 'my schema',
    'warehouse' : 'my warehouse',
    'role' : 'my role'
    }

query = "fake query limit 2500"
p = r"out csv path"
with snowflake.connector.connect(**credentials) as cnx:
    print("Running...")
    cur  = cnx.cursor()
    print("Executing query...")
    cur.execute(query)
    print("Fetch...")
    df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
    print(len(df))
    df.to_csv(p,  sep=',',  header=True,index=False)
end = time.time()
length = end - start
print("It took", round(length/60), "minutes!")
print("Done!!")



It sounds like you're running into a memory issue of some sort.
If you look at your code in its current form, it's going to attempt to load everything into a single DataFrame. That could be fine to a certain size, but imagine if you had to do this for a billion rows.
Therefore, the first thing you want to do is process your result in batches rather than trying to load all the data in one go.
You can do that by replacing fetch_pandas_all with fetch_pandas_batches. That will look something like this:
def func(df, i)
  print("Starting to process DataFrame Number: ", i)
  print(len(df))
  df.to_csv(p,  sep=',',  header=True,index=False)
    cur.execute(query)
...
def main():
    i=1
    for my_df in cur.fetch_pandas_batches():
       fun(my_df, i)
       i++

    end = time.time()
    length = end - start

    print("It took", round(length/60), "minutes!")
    print("Done!!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    


Thanks for the tip. I will adopt that technique moving forward. However, I found that I was only experiencing this issue when running this code within a script that utilises Arcpy which is a python module that comes with ArcGIS. Once I ran the script independently in python 12, it worked as expected with good performance. I am still not sure why that is the case.
